# Android MiniPaint App adding Clear Option to clear Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, view, paint

Unable to add **Clear** option to clear the Canvas.

Tried Adding  :

> fun clear(){
>   extraCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)
>           path.reset()
>           extraBitmap.eraseColor(backgroundColor)
>           invalidate() }

*Initialised clear() function it in the MainActivity onOptionsItemSelected method. but the clear() function is not triggering bit the most in the onOptionsItemSelected is triggering.*

**My Full Code**

**MainActivity.kt**

> class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
>
> ```
> private val paintView: MyCanvasView? = null
>
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>
>     val myCanvasView = MyCanvasView(this)
> ```
>
> //        myCanvasView.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
>
> ```
>     myCanvasView.contentDescription = getString(R.string.canvasContentDescription)
>
>     setContentView(myCanvasView)
>
> }
>
> override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
>
>     val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
>
>     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
>
>     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
> }
>
> override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
>
>     return when (item.itemId) {
>
>         R.id.clear -> {
>
>             paintView?.clear()
> ```
>
> Toast.makeText(this , "Cleared",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
>                   return true
>               }
>
> ```
>         else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
>     }
>     return true
> }
> ```
>
> }

**MyCanvasView.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewConfiguration
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat

private const val STROKE_WIDTH = 12f

class MyCanvasView(context: Context) : View(context) {



    private lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
    private lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap

    private val backgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorBackground, null)
    private val drawColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorPaint, null)


    private val paint = Paint().apply {


        color = drawColor
        // Smooths out edges of what is drawn without affecting shape.
        isAntiAlias = true
        // Dithering affects how colors with higher-precision than the device are down-sampled.
        isDither = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE // default: FILL
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND // default: MITER
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND // default: BUTT
        strokeWidth = STROKE_WIDTH // default: Hairline-width (really thin)
    }

    private var path = Path()

    private var motionTouchEventX = 0f
    private var motionTouchEventY = 0f
    private var currentX = 0f
    private var currentY = 0f


    private val touchTolerance = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
    private lateinit var frame: Rect

    override fun onSizeChanged(width: Int, height: Int, oldWidth: Int, oldHeight: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight)
        if (::extraBitmap.isInitialized) extraBitmap.recycle()
        extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(extraBitmap)
        extraCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)
// Calculate a rectangular frame around the picture.
        val inset = 40
        frame = Rect(inset, inset, width - inset, height - inset)

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
        canvas?.drawRect(frame, paint)

    }

    private fun touchStart() {
        path.reset()
        path.moveTo(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
        currentX = motionTouchEventX
        currentY = motionTouchEventY
    }

    private fun touchMove() {
        val dx = Math.abs(motionTouchEventX - currentX)
        val dy = Math.abs(motionTouchEventY - currentY)
        if (dx >= touchTolerance || dy >= touchTolerance) {
            // QuadTo() adds a quadratic bezier from the last point,
            // approaching control point (x1,y1), and ending at (x2,y2).
            path.quadTo(
                currentX,
                currentY,
                (motionTouchEventX + currentX) / 2,
                (motionTouchEventY + currentY) / 2
            )
            currentX = motionTouchEventX
            currentY = motionTouchEventY
            // Draw the path in the extra bitmap to cache it.
            extraCanvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }
        invalidate()
    }

    private fun touchUp() {
        path.reset()
//        clear()
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        motionTouchEventX = event.x

        motionTouchEventY = event.y

        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> touchStart()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> touchMove()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> touchUp()
        }
        return true
    }

    fun clear() {
        extraCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)
        path.reset()
        extraBitmap.eraseColor(backgroundColor)
        invalidate()


    }
```

Comment: You never assign `paintView` after its initialization, so it's null in `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Perhaps you meant to assign the `MyCanvasView(this)` in `onCreate()` to `paintView`, instead of the `val myCanvasView` there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift reply. Can you please be more specific I did not understand.@MikeM.

Comment: You're calling `clear()` on `paintView`, but you never assign `paintView` anything except `null`. It seems like you meant to do `paintView = MyCanvasView(this)`, `paintView.contentDescription = ...`, `setContentView(paintView)` instead.

Comment: Hi, changed the `paintView` to `val myCanvasView = MyCanvasView(this)` now the app is crashing.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? I meant that you need to get rid of the `val myCanvasView`, and change your code in `onCreate()` to what I showed above.

Comment: `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val myCanvasView = MyCanvasView(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val myCanvasView = MyCanvasView(this)

//        myCanvasView.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        myCanvasView.contentDescription = 

getString(R.string.canvasContentDescription)

        setContentView(myCanvasView)

    }`

Comment: No, like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Jj50TIKCRqHT_Gxus92dY1piKgu9eq0/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: Thanks for your time, solved :)